# Next seven days auto date picker

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

I have two date pickers, if I select a date in the 1st calendar it must mark the next seventh date in the second calendar. Ex. 1st date will be selected in 1st calendar (01/01/22) then it must show (07/01/22) in the next calendar auto marked. Any idea to do this? I am new to react js. If I select Start date, then the end date must be filled with a date next seven days. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will differ on the date picker library you're using but something like this should work (pseudo code):

```
state: {
   datePicker1Val: null,
   datePIcker2Val: null
}

componentDidUpdate(_prevProps, prevState) {
   if(prevState.datePicker1Val !== this.state.datePicker1Val) {
      setState(datePicker2Val: datePicker1Val.addDays(7))
   }
}

<DatePicker1 
    onChange={val => setState(datePicker1Val: val)}
    val={datePicker1Val}
 />
 <DatePicker2 
    onChange={val => setState(datePicker2Val: val)}
    val={datePicker2Val}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import {DatePicker , Space} from 'antd';
import moment from 'moment';

const App = () => {
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(null);
  
  const onChange = date => setEndDate(moment(date).add(7, 'days'));

  return (
      <div>
        <h1>Date Select</h1>
        <Space direction='horizontal'>
          <DatePicker onChange={onChange} />
          <DatePicker value={endDate} disabled />
        </Space>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The asker has clearly stated that they are using material UI datepicker. Kindly update your solution.

Comment: yes, I am trying to do the same for all types of date pickers. and will update soon